# SwiftUI app freezes with no errors in console after attempting to move between textfields on same view

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple log in view comprising of two text fields, a navigation link to a registration view, a navigation link to a forgot password view and a log in button. I can select either text field and enter text, however attempting to press any other control on the view (textfield or navigation link) after entering text into either text field, simply freezes the app with no error messages logged in the console window.

I have seen in other posts relating to older versions of Xcode / swift that this type of behaviour can be explained by a continuous loop being executed on the main thread, however i can not see how this applies in my case?

```
struct LoginForm : View {

    @Binding var emailAddress :  String
    @Binding var password: String

    var body: some View{

        VStack(alignment: .leading){

            Text("Email address")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .bold()
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.leading, 12)
            TextField("Email",text:$emailAddress)
                .padding()


            Text("Password")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .bold()
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.leading, 12)
            SecureField("Password",text:$password)
                .padding()

        }


    }
}





struct LoginRootView : View {

    @State private var emailAddress: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var authData: AuthData


    var body: some View {


        Group{

            if self.authData.authenticationDidSucceed {

                OnBoardRootView()

            }else{

                NavigationView{

                    ZStack{

                        Image("LoginBG")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio( contentMode: .fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            .opacity(0.5)


                        VStack(alignment: .leading){


                            Text( "Log into")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()


                            Text( "your account")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .bold()


                                LoginForm(emailAddress:$emailAddress, password:$password)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 8)
                                    .padding(.top, 22)






                            //Login button

                            if emailAddress != "" && password != ""{

                                LoginButton(email:self.emailAddress, password: self.password)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 20.0)
                                    .background(Color.blue, cornerRadius: 30.0)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)


                            }else{

                                LoginButton(email:self.emailAddress, password: self.password)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 20.0)
                                    .background(Color.gray, cornerRadius: 30.0)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                                    .disabled(emailAddress == "" || password == "")


                            }




                            //Forgot password link

                            HStack{

                                Text( "Forgot password?")


                                NavigationLink(destination: ForgotPasswordRootView()) {
                                    Text( "Get help signing in")
                                        .bold()

                                }

                            }.padding(.top, 20)


                            Spacer()

                            // Registration Link

                            HStack{

                                Text( "Don't have an account? ")

                                NavigationLink(destination: RegistrationRootView()) {
                                    Text( "Sign Up")
                                        .bold()

                                }

                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, 120)


                        }.padding(.all)
                            .padding(.top, 160)

                        // end of vstack


                    }

                    //end of zstack

                }
                //end of navigation view





            }
            //end of authentication if statement



        }
        //end of group




    }
}
```

Comment: I have observed the same, but it always happens with the simulator, not the real device. Additionally, I've only experienced that problem since beta 5, and only in Mojave. But I haven't been using Catalina too much lately, so that could be just a coincidence.

Comment: Based on your observation, i rebuilt the app and ran it on a different simulator (Xr instead of Xs) and although it appears the 'freezing' has stopped, i get this message in the console --- [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried your code with Xr simulator and I've seen the "Modifying state..." error only once, after I rebuilt and rerun multiple times, the error stopped showing. It is definitely a bug.

Comment: I suppose we will have to wait for beta 6 and deal with it for now :)

Comment: I have found that it doesn't lockup if you type enter before moving focus. I have filed a feedback (FB6910681) but not heard back.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm seeing the same on the latest Catalina release.

Comment: I'm also getting an error-less freeze, with 100% CPU usage, when revisiting a list item on an AS native app. (w/o any text fields) The fan doesn't blow after leaving it by accident for one hour, so there's that at least.

Answer (score 7):

You have to reset the simulator.

Simulator:

Hardware -> Erase All Content And Settings

Xcode:

1. Make clean build
2. Run

Answer (score 1):

Just to Restart the simulator can solve the issue.

```
Simulator -> Hardware -> Restart
```